# Getting error 'super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type ' using StanfordNERTagger

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

As per the post for NER with StanfordNERTagger, I have used the code  as below

```
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

#stanfordClassifierPath='stanford-ner/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz'
#stanfordPath='stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar'

st=StanfordNERTagger('/stanford-ner/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz','stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar',encoding='utf-8')

text='While in France, Christine Lagarde discussed short-term stimulus efforts in a recent interview with the Wall Street Journal.'

tokenized_text=word_tokenize(text)
classified_text=st.tag(tokenized_text)

print(classified_text)
```

However, upon executing this code I am getting below error

```
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 201, in __init__
    super(StanfordNERTagger, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

I am not able to fix this issue and dont know why this error is occurring. 
Appreciate if anyone can explain me the cause and solve this error.

Comment: Fix formatting.